# Android: how to update an Android app with inapp billing?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

Another way to ask the question: how to make inapp billing working with all versions of my app?

I have got an app with inapp billing. I want to update it.

My active apk on the developer console is in version 1. My problem is the following:

- when I install my updated app (signed package) in version 2 on my device using adb, I get the following message: "This version of the application package is not configured for Market billing"
- when I install my updated app (always signed package) in version 1 (same version as the one on the console) on my device (what I can't do on the console...I have to increase the version number !) using adb, verything works...

Consequently, it seems that inapp billing works only with one version of the app: the one which is active in the console. I imagine that my users will have the same issue: only the users with the last update of the app will be able to perform inapp billing...the others will get the error.

Anybody knows how to solve this issue ? How can I do so that all my apps already installed in the world will be able to do inapp billing whatever the version number is ??

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 6):

By "console" do you mean your publisher's account?

I think this isn't a bug but a feature by design. If you attempt to make a purchase that *doesn't* have one of the 4 `android.test.*` item ids, *and* it is running a debug version or even a release version that is **newer** than the one you have published, you will receive this error:

[image]

For example, if you're running on your device a **Release** mode that's one version higher than what's in the Market *and* you try to purchase a **real** item (not an `android.test.*` one), you will get the aforementioned error.

To further clarify: If you run an application of a higher versionCode than the one in the AndroidMarket (with the same package name, of course) it *will* succeed in "making the purchase" if you use one of the 4 `android.test.*` item ids.

Please note that this is based on my own experience and observation as full documentation on this leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

i face this error. solution:please upload sign apk and test with your Product id:com.test.purchased and set as a in-app product.
(1)run on your mobile using export with sign apk .
(2)if error is occur then wait 1-2 hours because sometime google take response late.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have observed while using In-App-Billing.

- When you upload your release apk (regardless of Alpha/Beta/Production), IAB will not work right away, you will have to wait for a few hours before it can work
- Uploading a new version of the apk (higher version) will also be the same. You will have to wait for a few hours for it to eventually work. The older version with IAB will still work though. What I usually do is to upload my release apk as Beta, wait a few hours, then when it is already working, promote the apk to production.